# Do Lorentz invariance and General covariance always hold at low energies, or are they sometimes violated?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, lorentz-symmetry

This is motivated by Weinberg’s folk theorem, where the construction of our perturbative expansion (and choice of theory space) is mostly safe given that we only have to enforce very general symmetry principles like the two I mentioned above.

So, I was wondering whether we could be confident in their characterizing physics at the energy scales we currently have access to. Any resource recommendations, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they hold. There are no cases we know of that exhibit Lorentz violation. That doesn't rule them out, but it largely means if it happens, it probably would have to happen in a special circumstance.

edit: Aside maybe for one case, CPT violation which is a type of Lorentz violation in quantum theory. Also for everyone else, Lorentz transformations preserve the assumption that the rules of physics should be the same in every coordinate frame, and it is General Covariance that allows General Relativity to assume the laws of physics are the same in every coordinate frame.